# Get component props from an array of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, jsx

I'm working on a react component. Imagine I have an array like this:

```
let data: {title: ReactNode}[] = [
   {title: "test1"}, 
   {title: <Component1 title="test2" />},
   {title: "200"},
   {title: <Component2 title="test3" />}
 ]
```

And I have a getTitle method:

```
let result = {};

const getTitle = () => {

 data.map((item, index) => {
  switch (typeof item.title) {
    case "string":
      result[index] = item.title;
      break;
    case "object":
      result[index] = item.title;
      break;
  }
});

};
```

For the component, it returns an object like this:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
```

and then when I want to access the props object (`item.title.props`), It returns an error:

```
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'ReactFragment'.ts(2339)
```

Is it possible to get the components' props inside an array of Reactnode?

Answer (score -1):

Since your component is functional, try the following

```
//previous cases...
  case "object":
      result[index] = item.title().props.title;
      break;
```

*edit*

```
 //previous cases...
      case "object":
          result[index] = item.title.props.title;
          break;
```

Comment: This expression is not callable.
If I try to like this: 
item.title().props.title
It returns an error:
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'